# How to hide the first response once the the yes button is pressed?

Tags: javascript, html

Managed to get the words to appear when a certain button is pressed thanks to you guys. Just need help with one more thing. I've tried using google, only found some ideas, but wasn't working well. This is just something simple.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article>

  <!-- insert clickable box here -->

  <p id="q1">Want to play a game?</p>
  <br>
  <button type="button" onclick="buttonYes1()" id="byes1">Yes</button>
  <button type="button" onclick="buttonNo1()" id="bno1">No</button>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    function buttonYes1() {
      document.getElementById("yes").style.display = "block";
    }

    // code to hide first question after yes button is pressed
    var button = document.getElementById('byes1')
    button.addEventListener('click', hideshow, false);

    function byes1() {
      document.getElementById('byes1').style.display = 'block';
      this.style.display = 'none'
    }

    function buttonNo1() {
      document.getElementById("no").style.display = "block";
    }
  </script>

  <!-- if yes, show detailed message -->
  <p id="yes" style="display: none;">random words</p>

  <!-- if no, show thanks for playing -->
  <p id="no" style="display: none;">no words</p>

  <!-- if yes, followed by detailed message, insert question #2 here -->

  <p id="q2">Qusetion number 2 goes here</p>

  <button type="button" onclick="buttonYes2()">Yes</button>
  <button type="button" onclick="buttonNo2()">No</button>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    function buttonYes2() {
      document.getElementById("yes2").style.display = "block";
    }

    function buttonNo2() {
      document.getElementById("no2").style.display = "block";
    }
  </script>

  <!-- if yes to question #2, give instructions on what to do -->
  <p id="yes2" style="display: none;">random words 2</p>

  <!-- if no to question #2, order soda, game ends -->
  <p id="no2" style="display: none;">no words 2</p>


</article>
```

So my question here is, how can I get the first question to disappear once the "yes" button is pressed? On top of that, I want to hide the second question until the user clicks on the "yes" button and that's when the question appears.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are asking for? See the snippet below:

```js
function buttonYes1() {
    var Yes1 = document.getElementById("yes")
    Yes1.style.display = "block";
    
    var question1Div = document.getElementById("question1Div")
    question1Div.style.display = "none";
    
    var question2Div = document.getElementById("question2Div")
    question2Div.style.display = "block";
}

// code to hide first question after yes button is pressed
var button = document.getElementById('byes1')
button.addEventListener('click',false);

function byes1() {
    document.getElementById('byes1').style.display = 'block';
    this.style.display = 'none'
}

function buttonNo1() {
    document.getElementById("no").style.display = "block";
}


function buttonYes2() {
    document.getElementById("yes2").style.display = "block";
}

function buttonNo2() {
    document.getElementById("no2").style.display = "block";
}
```

```html
<article>
<div id="question1Div">
    <!-- insert clickable box here -->
    <p id="q1">Want to play a game?</p>
    <br>
    <button type="button" onclick="buttonYes1()" id="byes1">Yes</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="buttonNo1()" id="bno1">No</button>
</div>
    <!-- if yes, show detailed message -->
    <p id="yes" style="display: none;">random words</p>

    <!-- if no, show thanks for playing -->
    <p id="no" style="display: none;">no words</p>


    <!-- if yes, followed by detailed message, insert question #2 here -->
<div id="question2Div" style="display:none;">
    <p id="q2">Qeustion number 2 goes here</p>

    <button type="button" onclick="buttonYes2()">Yes</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="buttonNo2()">No</button>
</div>
    <!-- if yes to question #2, give instructions on what to do -->
    <p id="yes2" style="display: none;">random words 2</p>

    <!-- if no to question #2, order soda, game ends -->
    <p id="no2" style="display: none;">no words 2</p>


</article>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is where you are going to have to put on your thinking cap as a programmer and start coming up with solutions.  Here is one way of doing this:

```js
var questionElements = document.getElementsByClassName('question');
var currentQuestion = 1;

function answerQuestion(answer){
  //Handle the response
  switch(answer) {
    case 'Yes':
      //Do something here
      break;
    case 'No':
      //Do something else here
      break;
    default:
      console.log('Oops, how did you get here?');
   }
   
   //Display or remove each question
   [].forEach.call(questionElements, (qElement, index) => {
      if (index == currentQuestion - 1) {
        //Remove the answered question
        qElement.style.display = 'None';
      } else if (index == currentQuestion) {
        //Display the next question
        qElement.style.display = 'Block';
      }
   });
   
   //Prepare for the next question
   currentQuestion++;
   if (currentQuestion == questionElements.length) {
      //All finished, Do something
   }
}
```

```css
.question {
  display: none;
}

.question:first-of-type {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="question">
  <p>Question 1: Do you like eggs?</p>
</div>

<div class="question">
  <p>Question 2: Do you like ham?</p>
</div>

<div class="question">
  <p>Question 3: Do you like green eggs and ham?</p>
</div>

<button onclick="answerQuestion('Yes');">Yes</button>
<button onclick="answerQuestion('No');">No</button>
```